# Show an alert when mouse is on a div for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have certain `div` in the page and I need to do this:

> When the user mouse stands on the `div` for 2 seconds without moving out, then an alert will show

I came here because I don't really know where to start, what to do, how to make it.

I searched on the web but I got no results. Any tutorial, resources, guide or example would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When hovering over the element, use `setTimeout` to request an alert box, with a delay of 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds). Reset the timer using `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` when the user moves the mouse.

Example, **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6SyLb/1/**

```
var div = document.getElementById("thediv");
function alerter(){
    alert("Test")
    timer = setTimeout(alerter, 2000);
}
var timer;
div.onmousemove = function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(alerter, 2000)
};
div.onmouseover= function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(alerter, 2000)
}
div.onmouseout = function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

Comment: that's working great , i'll mark as solve as soon as i can , thanks.

Comment: Note that this does not work on Chrome, because `mousemove` is fired every so many milliseconds, even when you do not actually move the mouse: http://jsfiddle.net/6SyLb/2/.

Comment: @pimvdb Just add a comparison check of the values of `event.pageX`, `event.pageY`: http://jsfiddle.net/6SyLb/3/